# CONCAT and SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a form that searches through the database for a result. The result is made up of two of the columns. 
I am trying to CONCAT them in order to have it search both of these columns for the result. Once it finds it, I want it to print out that row.

My error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE CONCAT(Type,' ',Identifier) = Library 110' at line 1.

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die (mysql_error());
$db_selected = mysql_select_db ('test',$link);

$term = $_POST['term'];
if ($sql = mysql_query ("SELECT CONCAT(Type,' ',Identifier) as srcqry WHERE CONCAT(Type,' ',Identifier) = $term "))
{   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo '<br/> Location: '.$row['Location'];
    echo '<br/> Section: '.$row['Section'];
    echo '<br/> Identifier: '.$row['Type']. ' ' .$row['Identifier'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
}
else 
{
echo die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Need to know your RDBMS (your program).  `CONCAT` differs.

Comment: ... and I doubt you can use `CONCAT` in `WHERE` ... ?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL needs a FROM clause.  Although mysql supports "SELECT " it does not support it with a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing with:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Type,' ',Identifier) as srcqry FROM TableName WHERE CONCAT(Type,' ',Identifier) = '$term'
```

ie. Add the table name with `FROM` clause and `'` around `$term`.

However as [@Jack Maney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398426/concat-and-sql-queries/11398593#comment15027842_11398426) has pointed out, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.